# javascript pattern matching only returns first hit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match some strings like '[932A]' in Javascript. The condensed version is:

```
'[625A] [625B] [625C]'.match(/\[[0-9]*[A-Z]+\]/)
```

is returning an array with 1 element, the first hit. Is it obvious why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a global regex, using the final `g` term

```
 '[625A] [625B] [625C]'.match(/[[0-9]*[A-Z]+]/g)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that you want to get all of the matches with the global flag. For example (note the ending g):

```
/[0-9]/g
```

You also need to escape square brackets when they are not being used to delimit a character class. For example:

```
/\[[0-9]+\]/
```

Which would match one or more digits inside of square brackets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the extra backslashes are necessary given that they don't contain character classes... They contain other syntax that ensures the outer square brackets are normal characters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply need to add on the global flag in your regular expression. That's done by adding a 'g' to the end of it. Your resulting regular expression should look like this:

```
/[[0-9]*[A-Z]+]/g
```